# Multilingual multisite > customisable footer across different sites with widgets?

Tags: multisite, widgets

I'd like to keep the structure of the footer similar across all sites using the same Theme. However, each site would need different content in their footer.
Here's a concrete example - for Site A:

```
SECTION A1                 SECTION A2
1                          3
2                          4
```

and for Site B:

```
SECTION B1                 SECTION B2
5                          7
6                          8
```

I thought about widgetising the footer so people could add whatever content they want but, as the sites will eventually be multilingual, I checked and heard there could be some problems with multilingual widgets.

Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: In a multisite, each site has usually one language. Widgets do not interfere with other sites, so this is one of the very few safe places.

Comment: So if you have 5 languages per site and 4 sites (e.g. A,B,C,D) then you'd need to create 20 sites in the WordPress Multisite? Doesn't seem very DRY.

Comment: An additional sites doesn't create much overhead. Mixing multiple languages in one site is much more fragile. I would build separate networks per topic, so you have just one network for each former site.